# how to send auth from ios to remote server php

Tags: php, ios

I am building an iOS application and I need to be able to make authenticated requests to a php 5 application for various bits of data. The php 5 application is using codeigniter framework and URLs like https://example.com/controller/function to, for example, authenticate users via twitter... and once authenticated, stores the authentication in a secured cookie named "auth.""

What I want to know is how to authenticate my users from the iOS/iPhone application, persist the authentication token and send it along with future requests to the codeigniter application?

Answer (score 0):

The big picture is that you need to implement something like an api controller in the code igniter app.  This controller should have an "auth" method.  At some point, you're going to want to pass a hash of the twitter cookie to the ios app.  Then, for each subsequent call to the api controller, send along the hash, your code igniter app will associate the hash with the properly authenticated user and allow it access.  If anyone else tries to access the api calls, they will either fail to do it, and be denied, or they will supply a guess and be denied.

So from your ios app's perspective, all its subsequent calls (after authentication) will look like:

```
https://example.com/api/<function name>/<session hash>
```